# Convolving Room Impulse Response with a Wav File (python)

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, convolution, acoustics

I have written the following code which is supposed to put echo over an available sound file. Unfortunately the output is a very noisy result which I don't exactly understand. Can anybody help me with regard to this? Is there any skipped step?

```
#convolving a room impulse response function with a sound sample both of stereo type
from scipy.io import wavfile
    inp=wavfile.read(sound_path+sound_file_name)
    IR=wavfile.read(IR_path+IR_file_name)
    if inp[0]!=IR[0]:
        print "Size mismatch"
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        rate=inp[0]
    print sound_file_name
    out_0=fftconvolve(inp[1][:,1],IR[1][:,0])
    out_1=fftconvolve(inp[1][:,1],IR[1][:,1])
    in_counter+=1
    out=np.vstack((out_0,out_1)).T
    out[:inp[1].shape[0]]=out[:inp[1].shape[0]]+inp[1]
    wavfile.write(sound_path+sound_file_name+'_echoed.wav',rate,out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Wav files are imported as int16 files and modification should be done after converting them to floats:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-pysoundfile.ipynb

After convolution one needs to renormalize again. And thats it.

Hope this helps the others too.

```
from utility import pcm2float,float2pcm
    input_rate,input_sig=wavfile.read(sound_path+sound_file_name)
    input_sig=pcm2float(input_sig,'float32')
    IR_rate,IR_sig=wavfile.read(IR_path+IR_file_name)
    IR_sig=pcm2float(IR_sig,'float32')

    if input_rate!=IR_rate:
        print "Size mismatch"
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        rate=input_rate
    print sound_file_name
    con_len=-1
    out_0=fftconvolve(input_sig[:con_len,0],IR_sig[:con_len,0])
    out_0=out_0/np.max(np.abs(out_0))
    out_1=fftconvolve(input_sig[:con_len,1],IR_sig[:con_len,1])
    out_1=out_0/np.max(np.abs(out_1))
    in_counter+=1
    out=np.vstack((out_0,out_1)).T
        wavfile.write(sound_path+sound_file_name+'_'+IR_file_name+'_echoed.wav',rate,float2pcm(out,'int16'))
```

One can download utility from the above link.

**UPDATE:** Although it generates a working output its still not as good as the result when using the original website **[Openair](http://www.openairlib.net/auralizationdb/content/elveden-hall-suffolk-england)** for convolving.

Answer (score 2):

Adding echo to a sound file is just that... *adding echo.*  Your code doesn't look like it's adding two sounds together; it looks like it's transforming the input sound into something else.

Your data flow should look something like this:

```
source sound ------------------------------>|
      |                                     + ----------> target sound
      ---------> convolution echo --------->|
```

Note that your echo sound is going to be longer than your original sound (i.e. it has a "tail.")

Adding two sounds together is simply a matter of adding each of the individual samples together from both sounds to produce a new output wave.  I don't think `vstack` does that.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the issue but the result is still incorrect. regardign the `vstack` thats for putting two channels together.

Comment: I'd start by making sure that the echo (just the echo) sounds like it is supposed to.

Comment: Well my first code as you explained was only the echo and it was not sounding as it was expected. Its quite noisy as opposed to the case when I am using an online source to do the convolution:
http://www.openairlib.net/auralizationdb/content/elveden-hall-suffolk-england

Comment: btw, I am using the same impulse response function in the above link.